# form resets after pressing ok button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to write a simple page where I press the ok button, it gets the title and text for the query parameter on the page. However, after it loads, it seems to reset the query parameter and ends up getting the same data.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 // left / right arrows
 $(document).keydown(function(e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 39) {
  $(".move:focus")
    .next()
    .focus();
   }
   if (e.keyCode == 37) {
  $(".move:focus")
    .prev()
    .focus();
   }
 });

 function okClick() {
   var urlToUse = 'http://localhost:3000/test?qp=' + $("#myQueryParam").val();
   return $.ajax({
  url: urlToUse,
  type: "GET",
   });
 }

 okClick().done(function(result) {
    console.log("Success", result);
  $("#title").text(result.title);
  $("#iText").text(result.text);
  $("#myQueryParam").val(result.myQueryParam);
  console.log('All done');
 }).fail(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    alert("Something went wrong");
 });

 $("#b1").one(okClick);

 $("#b2").click(function(e) {
   alert("bb");
   // add to history
 });
 console.log("ready!");
    
}); // end document.ready
```

```css
 #myProj{
        background-color: green;
        width: 100%;
        color: #333333;
        height: 300px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 10px 0;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-around;
        display: flex;
        float: right;
    }
    
    :focus {
            outline: 20px solid red;
    }
        
    button:focus {
            background: pink;
    }
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<div id="myProj">
  <div class="container">
 <form id=myForm>
   <div class="form-group">
  <!-- type="hidden" -->
  <span class="label label-default dd">myQueryParam</span>
  <input id="myQueryParam" name="queryParam" value="0" />
  <h1 id="title">Title</h1>
  <div class="label label-info" id="iText">Text</div>
   </div>
   <button id="b1" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary move">
  OK
   </button>
   <button id="b2" type="button" class="btn btn-dark move">
  Cancel
   </button>
 </form>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"  integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Initially myQueryParam is 0, it becomes 1 after first call. But becomes zero again before second call and gets the same data.

Comment: If an input or button tag with `type="submit"` or a button tag ***without a `type` attribute*** that is nested within a form tag (or has a `form` attribute) will trigger a submit event. A submit event will **reset** the form. So if you find that behavior inconvenient (most people do) then add `e.preventDefault()` to the first line of the offending function (the click handler that you unwittingly assigned to a submit button) or just change `type="submit"` to `type="button"`

Comment: I feel like you're abstracting too much too early as well...  maybe try this approach...  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rXWooo

Comment: There's no need to change from `.done()` to `success:` - just make sure it's in the correct place.